# Number increment jQuery showing null number error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem with the below jQuery and HTML is, when I scroll to the section `#amount_counter`, the class `.count-data` number got start increment and count, but after loaded to the data value, it returns and stops to a null number. May I know where the error is?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var scrollTop = $("#amount_counter");
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var topPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    if (topPos > 400) {
      $('.count-data').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
          Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
          duration: 4000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function(now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="amount_counter">
  <div class="row">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="count-data">24</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="count-data">400000000</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve bound the `scroll` event and check `topPos > 400` for every single scroll. Once the condition hits, you could still scroll further and the condition would hit *again*. This would trigger the `animate` call again, scheduled after the current animation ends, with a current, intermediate value. Since `$(this).text()` may contain a `,`, it can’t be parsed as a number anymore and you get `NaN`.

Just detach the event listener as soon as the condition is first met:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var scrollTop = $("#amount_counter");

  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var topPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (topPos > 400) {
      $(window).off("scroll");

      $('.count-data').each(function() {
        // …
      });
    }
  });
});
```

If you want to restart the animation, using a different value, utilize the [`complete`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) callback within your `animate` options and bind `scroll` again.